# How do I select nth element in a given set

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select first span, second span or last span for the following html?

```html
<div>
    <b>Text<b/>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

How can I select the nth element in a given set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `nth-child` selector:

```
span:nth-child(2) {}
```

This selects the first span since it's the second child. If you want to select the second span, you can use this instead:

```
span:nth-of-type(2) {}
```

You can also use `first-child`, `last-child`, `nth-child(odd)` or `nth-child(even)`, among others.

Comment: SoKeT, Hitting the CSS boards this afternoon!  Thanks for your effort!  I'll throw some thank you bounty in a couple days :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, but I see that the span in the first div is getting selected when it shouldn't. That's because you misstyped the closing p tag. It's `<p/>` when it should be `</p>`.

Comment: @SoKeT I updated that,  that's only a typo, not what I wanna ask

Comment: I guess you're referring to this comment: /* why 2 instead of 1 */. In that case, it's because `<p>` is the second child of its parent `<div>`. If you want to select the first `<p>` tag you have to use `p:nth-of-type(1)` or `p:first-of-type`.

Answer (score 0):

use n-th child if i make that code for example in this way i Specify  background color is blue for  every

tag element that is the second child of it parent is:

```
p:nth-child(2) {
background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child` selector allows you to select one or more elements based on their source order, according to a formula

The formula is constructed using the syntax `an+b`, where:

```
"a" is an integer value
"n" is the literal letter "n"
"+" is an operator and may be either "+" or "-"
"b" is an integer and is required if an operator is included in the formula
```

Here are some ways you can achieve this as per your requirement:

```css
div span:first-child {

}
div span:nth-child(an+b) {

}
div span:last-child {

}
```

Here are some other relative properties you can use as well:

- `nth-last-child`
- `nth-of-type`
- `nth-last-of-type`
- `first-of-type`
- `last-of-type`